# Copying multiple strings to clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I like to copy multiple string objects to the MS Excel Clipboard but seem to be unable to do it. What I get is the last thing that is copied. Hope to receive some help here. I copied the below codes from a website and made my own changes but unable to make it work.

```
Sub CopyTextToClipboard()

Dim obj As New DataObject
Dim txt1, txt2, txt3 As String

  txt1 = "This was copied to the clipboard using VBA! (Text 1)"
  obj.SetText txt1
  obj.PutInClipboard

  txt2 = "This was copied to the clipboard using VBA! (Text 2)"
  obj.SetText txt2
  obj.PutInClipboard

  txt3 = "This was copied to the clipboard using VBA! (Text 3)"
  obj.SetText txt3
  obj.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```

The only string that got copied to the clipboard was `txt3`. I believe that all were copied but got written over by the last string. I like to ask how I can have multiple strings copied to the clipboard like how I could do so manually. Thanks.

Note: If it helps, I'm using Windows10 and Excel 2016.

Comment: Note that if you declare `Dim txt1, txt2, txt3 As String` only `txt3` is of type `String` the others are of type `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim txt1 As String, txt2 As String, txt3 As String` otherwise it is `Variant` by default.

Comment: It looks like a [X/Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you describe the purpose of doing that? What do you want to achieve? What is your actual goal of all this?

Comment: Hi @PEH Thanks for your feedback. The reason to do this is a long and complex one but I'll try to simplify as much as possible. There are cells that my colleagues and I are working on that require the input of some standard strings. We find it a chore to have to select the cells containing those string, copy and paste and do a "double double click" into the cell and paste the string. We are able to do so more efficiently with all the items copied to a clipboard and paste by clicking on that string in the clipboard. I hope this is enough information. 

Comment: Well clipboard works like this: You copy and if you paste it will always paste whatever was last copied. That's it. If that is not what you want then clipboard is not the correct tool for your task.

Comment: @PEH's comment is correct: `PutInClipboard` overwrites the previous content of the clipboard. A limited solution can be to read the content of the clipboard and append the new content to it separated by an appropriate separator that is unlikely to show up in the text. E.g. `obj.GetFromClipboard :  tc = obj.GetText(1) : obj.SetText tc & "|" & txt3 : obj.PutInClipboard`. Then somewhen later you can `Split` the string by that separator.

Comment: @AcsErno could be an answer instead of a comment. But still I don't see the advantage of using the clipboard then, because on paste it would insert all of it anyway. And if you don't use the normal paste then you don't need to use the clipboard at all, then you could just use a global variable and a dictionary, array or collection.